# If my Android APK Bundle is say 45 MB will that be the size of my application when it hits Google Play Store?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, google-play-console

I'm a noob please help me out here. Now I'm aware Google has a new rule in making our Apk support for 64-bit. I have done that, but targeting for each architecture has led my Apk bundle size hit 44MB all the way up from like 15MB with Mono and it's default ARMv7 targetting on Unity. Does this mean my APK will be a size of 44MB when it hits Google Play Store? Or is that just a reflection of multiple APKs being chunks of that 44MB? I'm hoping that my individual APK for x architecture device will be still around that 15MB mark or so when the user has to download the application, so do I need to worry about this during the internal/closed tests and actual publishing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so turns out I would've got the answer anyway had I just uploaded the APK bundle as it was. So while it happens in the Google Play Console, Google estimates the actual size of each APK download size which will be between X - Y MB.